Azure CLI not recognized after restarting powershell
I've installed the Azure Command Line Interface and verified by using
azcopy --version
However, upon closing and re-running powershell, that same command gives me an error az command not recognized as a cmdlet
If I re-install (repair) AZ CLI using the official installer, it works again.
What's causing this weird issue?

Please provide more details about the issue

Where you have installed the Azure Command Line Interface?

This question is similar to: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Refer this Blog

The difference is that it first works and then doesn't (upon restarting powershell)

Try running az --version
